# UIView not updating constraints in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, uideviceorientation

I have a UIViewController which has a UIView that plays a video.

The constraints given to this UIView are as follows.

Trailing space to : Superview

Leading space to :Superview

Top space to Superview

Bottom space to : Bottom layout guide

When I run the app in portrait mode it works fine. When I change the orientation to landscape by turning the iPhone it retains the same width and height as that of the portrait mode and does not play the video in full screen

The current orientation in the storyboard is portrait in iPhone 7.

When I rotate the orientation in the storyboard board to landscape and run the app it runs in full screen as expected but the UIView does not resize it in portrait mode.

While adding constraints to the UIView in storyboard for portrait mode, I have also added constraints for landscape mode.

I have also tried to add a variation  for each constraint constant.

I am not able to figure out what the problem is. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you added the landscape orientation for your project?

Comment: No I have set it to Potrait in Info.plist , and on the view that I am rotating I have followed the following tutorial and enabled landscape mode . http://www.jairobjunior.com/blog/2016/03/05/how-to-rotate-only-one-view-controller-to-landscape-in-ios-slash-swift/. I am able to rotate the view controller. The problem is that the uiview does not get align with the landscape orientation constraints

Comment: Two thoughts. (1) *"....I have also added constraints for landscape mode...."* Could you provide some detail as to what this means? Between the lack of *how* all these constraints were made - IB, code, priorities - it's difficult to know if you are getting conflicts or what is happening. (2) These videos being played in a UIView - is it possible that the constraints *are* working but the *contentMode* (scaleAspectFit, etc.) is kicking in to make it "appear" that they aren't?

Comment: 1)While viewing in the view controller in the storyboard in portrait mode I have added the above constraints, and also for the view controller in landscape mode I have added constraints . These constraints were added in the interface builder. I have also tried Vary for traits

Comment: 2) The content mode is set to Aspect fit as well

Comment: Set a breakpoint where you expect everything to be set correctly, and then use the XCode constraints view, to view what the actual constraints and sizes during runtime are. See e.g. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with rotation of my UIView and I found the solution:

Transform the view based on the device orientation angle:

```
customView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
```

Adjust the frame of the view to fit the new orientation:

```
customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: containerView.bounds.width, height: containerView.bounds.height)
```

or:

```
customView.frame = containerView.bounds
```

Update the constraints and trigger a layout update to ensure that the view and its subviews are properly positioned and resized:

```
customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
customView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
customView.setNeedsLayout()
customView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I hope this or something similar helps.